Slate.js - trying and failing to update the text of a custom node using Transforms.setNodes
For example, I will have an editor.children layout like so:
  [
    {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [
        {
          text: 'A line of text!',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'variable',
      id: '12345',
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Text to be changed',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      type: 'paragraph',
      children: [
        {
          text: 'A line of text!',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],

And I'm trying to change the text at [0,1,0] ("Text to be changed") to a new value. I'm using this function:
const updateVariableName = (editor, variableId, updatedName) => {
  let variableChipPath = null;

  for (const [node, path] of Node.nodes(editor)) {
    if (node.variableId === variableId && Element.isElement(node)) {
      variableChipPath = path;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (variableChipPath) {
    const textNodePath = [...variableChipPath, 0];
    Transforms.setNodes(editor, { text: updatedName }, { at: textNodePath });
  }
}

From everything I've read on the docs this seems like it should work. I'm getting the correct variableChipPath as [0, 1]. If I instead write the last line as:
Transforms.setNodes(editor, { id: "67890" }, { at: variableChipPath});

The id updates appropriately. I just can't seem to target children[0].text. Any ideas?
